# DB2 using parameteres in like statement

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, db2

The problem is as following:
I have a Procedure in DB2 that receives couple parameters and does a filtering.
One of the parameters is a VARCHAR thath is needed for a like statement. In SQLServer I simply join the string like so `'%'+prmName+'%'`, naturally this won't work in DB2 and needs to be replaced with `'%'||prmName||'%'`. 
But then this error pops up:

`DB2 Database Error: ERROR [42824] [IBM][DB2/NT] SQL0132N  A LIKE predicate or POSSTR scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string expression or the second operand is not a string.  A LOCATE or POSITION scalar function is not valid because the first operand is not a string or the second operand is not a string expression.  LINE NUMBER=6.  SQLSTATE=42824`

After Google-ing the error I found out that DB2 cannot support column names and parameter in `LIKE` statements, among couple of others.

Since I cant change the code of the application but I need to transfer the SQLServer procedure to DB2, any help to find the workaround is appreciated.

This is the code in SQLServer

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [DATABYUSERNAME]
    (
        @prmQuestionnaireId int,
        @prmStartDate DateTime,
        @prmEndDate DateTime,
        @prmUserName nvarchar(100)
    )       
AS
    SELECT * from ExecutedQuestionnaire EQ left outer join SecurityUserTable SUT
    on EQ.CreatedBy = SUT.UserId
    where EQ.CreationDate between @prmStartDate and @prmEndDate
    and SUT.Name LIKE '%'+@prmUserName+'%'
    and EQ.QuestionnaireId = @prmQuestionnaireId        
    RETURN
```

And this is the try of the select statement in DB2:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE bla VARCHAR(100);
DECLARE search VARCHAR(100);
set bla = 'sup';

SELECT EQ.EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIREID,EQ.EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIRESTATUSID,EQ.CREATIONDATE,EQ.CREATEDBY,EQ.ISCOMPLETE,EQ.QUESTIONNAIREID,
                    SUT.NAME, SUT.USR
    FROM EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIRE EQ 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SECURITYUSERTABLE SUT
    ON EQ.CREATEDBY = SUT.USERID
    WHERE EQ.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN '2010-12-01' and '2011-12-01'
    AND UPPER(SUT.NAME) LIKE Upper(CAST('%'||bla||'%' as VARCHAR(100)))
    AND EQ.QUESTIONNAIREID = 1;
END
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [**`LOCATE()`**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/flocate.htm):

```
AND LOCATE(UPPER(bla), UPPER(SUT.NAME)) > 0
```

---

Another issue is I think the length of the VARCHAR variable you declare. Have you tried if this works?:

```
BEGIN ATOMIC
DECLARE bla CHAR(5);
DECLARE search VARCHAR(100);
set bla = '%SUP%';

SELECT EQ.EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIREID,EQ.EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIRESTATUSID,EQ.CREATIONDATE,EQ.CREATEDBY,EQ.ISCOMPLETE,EQ.QUESTIONNAIREID,
                    SUT.NAME, SUT.USR
    FROM EXECUTEDQUESTIONNAIRE EQ 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN SECURITYUSERTABLE SUT
    ON EQ.CREATEDBY = SUT.USERID
    WHERE EQ.CREATIONDATE BETWEEN '2010-12-01' and '2011-12-01'
    AND UPPER(SUT.NAME) LIKE bla
    AND EQ.QUESTIONNAIREID = 1;
END
```

According to [**LIKE**](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/dzichelp/v2r2/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.doc.sqlref/flocate.htm):

> When the pattern specified in a LIKE predicate is a parameter marker and a fixed-length character host variable is used to replace the parameter marker, specify a value for the host variable that is the correct length. **If you do not specify the correct length**, the select does not return the intended results. For example, if the host variable is defined as CHAR(10) and the value WYSE% is assigned to that host variable, **the host variable is padded with blanks** on assignment.

Comment: @Drakche: Then this?: `AND UPPER(SUT.NAME) LIKE Upper('%'|| CAST(bla as CHAR(3)) ||'%')`

Comment: `set bla = '%SUP%';` can't be used, because I need to pass the value. 'SUP' is a dummy value. But the first solution works. Thanks.